# Updating to CM11 - (Status 7) Installation aborted (i9300)

Tags: cyanogenmod, clockworkmod-recovery, boot

I'm trying to install CM11 onto my Samsung Galaxy S3 (i9300) so I can have the new Google Camera and Chrome Remote Desktop apps.

I tried to install initially via the usual update menu, but got an error and it went to ClockworkRecovery Mod. After much messing around, I downloaded [this zip](http://download.cyanogenmod.com/get/jenkins/64374/cm-11-20140405-SNAPSHOT-M5-i9300.zip) and put it onto an SD card and tried to install it using CWM but I get the following error:

> Error in cm-11-2014005-SNAPSHOT-M5-i9300.zip (Status 7) Installation
> aborted

Any ideas please? It sucks being without a phone, and I don't want to wipe everything and start again if I can help it since I'm pretty sure I have things on there that aren't backed up (that'll be my first job when I get this working again!)

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you sure your S3 is the i9300?  `GT-I9300` is the international model of the S3.  If you are in the US, your model number is most likely different depending on the carrier you bought it from (unless you imported it from overseas.)  [Here](http://www.etradesupply.com/blog/find-models-samsung-galaxy-s3-series/) is a listing of all the S3 model numbers.  After determining your S3's actual model number, you can download the proper version of the ROM from [here](http://download.cyanogenmod.org/).

Comment: Thank you, I'm from the UK and it definitely is the i9300 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to answer my phone question on here, but finally sorted it! Thanks to Adach1979 for pointing me towards a useful resource too.

In the end I had to put CM10.2 onto the SD card and install that using CWM - it wiped all of my data (urgh) but at least the phone was working again.

I then used Cyanogenmod's fantastic installer to get the latest version - http://beta.download.cyanogenmod.org/install

I then had issues where the USB kept disconnecting, apparently this is common on Samsung devices and I managed to fix it by using Zadig and these instructions - http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/82393-samsung-devices-we-couldnt-talk-to-your-phone/

And now, almost 4 hours after I started, CM11 is finally installed on my phone! :)

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search turned up [this](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/84504-cm-11-on-galaxy-s3-gt-i9300-stastus-7-error/).

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I cannot install the previous version since it seems I can't browse through the files on my phone using CWM :( I can only browse through the SD card, and I cannot remember the exact version I used before

Comment: Quick update - I'm trying now with cm-10.2.0-i9300! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

just to collect more information with this question for future use of it, what Recovery did you use? Maybe the zip you downloaded was corrupted or for another device. Indeed, I had the same problem with my I9505 trying flashing a Niglty build of CM11.
Let me know!

Regards,

Luca

Comment: Hi,I tried to use CWM - not sure what version sorry! I did try installing two different versions of CM11 though and got the same problem both times. I also tried editing one of the files in a text editor as recommended by an online guide but no joy with that either. I think the problem was possibly due to using an old CWM version

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the recovery. Use the recommended version of CWM recovery. Also check the md5 checksum of the CM11 zip file u downloaded to see if its intact.